# Applying the dominated convergence theorem back and forth

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Suppose $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ is a measure space, $(f_{n})$ and $(g_{n})$ two sequences of integrable functions that tend to $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, respectively. Suppose also that 
$$|f_{n}g_{n}|\leq h_{1},$$
$$|f_{n}|\leq h_{2}$$
for $h_{1}$ and $h_{2}$ integrable so that we can use dominated convergence theorem for $ f_{n}g_{n} $  and for $ f_{n} $. Is it correct to apply back and forth dominated convergence theorem and write:
\begin{align*}
 \lim_{n \to \infty}\int f_{n}g_{n}d\mu&=\int\lim_{n \to \infty}f_{n}g_{n}d\mu\\
 &=\int\lim_{n \to \infty}f_{n}\lim_{n \to \infty}g_{n}d\mu\\
 &=\int\lim_{n \to \infty}f_{n}g d\mu\\
 &=\lim_{n \to \infty}\int f_{n}g d\mu?
\end{align*}

Comment: in what topology do $f_n$ and $g_n$ converge to $f,g$? you should specify that in the beginning of your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason why $\int f_ng$ should even exist. On $(0,1)$ with Lebesgue measure let $f_n\equiv \frac 1 n, g_n(x)=\frac 1 x I_{(\frac 1 n, 1)}$. Then $f_n \to f=0$, $g_n \to g$ where $g(x)=\frac 1 x$ for all $x$ and the assumptions are satisfied with $h_1=h_2=1$. But $\int f_ng$ does not exist for any $n$. So the last step in your argument is not correct . All other steps are OK.

Comment: What if we know that $\int f_{n}gd\mu$ does exist?

Comment: @M.Rahmat You still cannot justify the last step.

Comment: Ok.  So if $ |f_{n}g|$ is bounded by an ingrable function then the last step is justified. Correct?

Comment: @M.Rahmat Of course, yes.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Thanks a lot.